# How to access JPL Horizons from javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get astronomical data from JPL Horizons https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/ using javascript. I just get null data back.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    async function getText(file) {
      
      let myObject = await fetch(file, {
        method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      });
      let myText = await myObject.text();
      return myText;
   
    }
    
    jplString = "https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&COMMAND='499'&OBJ_DATA='YES'&MAKE_EPHEM='YES'&EPHEM_TYPE='OBSERVER'&CENTER='500@399'&START_TIME='2006-01-01'&STOP_TIME='2006-01-20'&STEP_SIZE='1%20d'&QUANTITIES='1,9,20,23,24,29'"


    myText= getText(jplString);

    console.log(myText);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried varying the method and mode, without success.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.